# How do I calculate damage for the sorcerer's Dancing Lightning spell

Tags: dnd-4e

The level 3 encounter sorcerer spell Dancing Lightning deals 2d10 + Charisma modifier lightning damage to the primary target, and each creature adjacent to the target takes thunder damage equal to the Charisma modifier.

Now I know that to calculate the damage on the primary target, I need not just to take the "pure" Charisma modifier of the sorcerer (+4 in this case), but also need to add the +2 enhancement bonus of his staff and the +2 bonus of his draconic power, for a total of 2d10+8.

But how much damage do the adjacent creatures take? Just 4 as the pure Charisma modifier, or 8 because I add the same enhancement and class bonus as in the first case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magical implements as well as Draconic Power add the enhancement bonus to damage **rolls**.

The secondary effect on Dancing Lightning has no roll to it, it's just the Charisma modifier as damage.

Comment: I feel that it's worth noting that, if the splash damage were 1d6, it absolutely would benefit from all of those modifiers that add to damage rolls. Many tables don't realize this, which underplays the value of spectacularly powerful spells like Flame Spiral and Hellish Rebuke.